# Many Enums with same members in the same class

Tags: c++, enums

The title says it all, but I give an example here:

```
class A {
public:
  enum A 
  {
    enumVal1,
    enumVal2
  };

  enum B 
  {
    enumVal1,
    enumVal3,
  };
};
```

What do I have to do that this may work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++11 has scoped enumerations:

```
class S {
public:
  enum class A 
  {
    enumVal1,
    enumVal2
  };

  enum class B 
  {
    enumVal1,
    enumVal3,
  };
};
```

Then you need to refer to `A::enumVal1` and `B::enumVal1`. `enumVal2` must also be qualified even though there is no ambiguity. Also, the enumerators do not implicitly convert to and from `int` as in the old style; you need a `static_cast`.

This is just reifying a C++03 idiom:

```
class S {
public:
  struct A { enum type
  {
    enumVal1,
    enumVal2
  } value; };

  struct B { enum type 
  {
    enumVal1,
    enumVal3,
  } value; };
};
```

Then you need to either declare objects of type `A::type` and `B::type`, or refer to the `.value` member of `struct A`. (Other approaches are possible.)

Comment: enum class is not `just reifying a C++03 idiom`. It gives you strong typing, which is not achieved with old style enums

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, was mentioning that just as you commented. To be pedantic, it prevents implicit conversion; strong typing has always been a feature of enumerations. Actually that is also achievable in C++03 by declaring the object to be of type e.g. `A` or `B` and using appropriately-defined conversion operators.

Answer (score 4):

C++ doesn't allow you to have two identical identifiers in the same scope. You could add a prefix to make it clear:

```
  enum A 
  {
    A_enumVal1,
    A_enumVal2
  };

  enum B 
  {
    B_enumVal1,
    B_enumVal3
  };
```

Or you could put each enum in a different [namespace](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) and use `A::enumVal1`, `B::enumVal1`, etc. Namespaces were designed to solve problems like this.

Answer (score 4):

In `c++ 11` you can use `enum class`:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  enum class A 
  {
    enumVal1,
    enumVal2
  };

  enum class B 
  {
    enumVal1,
    enumVal3,
  };
};
```

Than you reference the values as:

```
MyClass::A::enumVal1
MyClass::B::enumVal1
```

Using `enum classes` instead of old enums also gives you strong typing. You can read more about `enum classes` [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html)